# How can I pass a state from the parent view to the child?

Tags: react-native

MyPinchZoomView has a state 'scale'.
In the setup below, how can the component 'board' keep track of the current scale?

```
 render() {
      return (
        <MyPinchZoomView
          minScale={0.9}
          maxScale={2}
          >
          { this.board }
        </MyPinchZoomView>
      )
  }
```

The same Question, if I would add the MyPinchZoomView **within** the board component:

```
 return (
      <View>
      <MyPinchZoomView
          minScale={0.9}
          maxScale={2}
          >
          { this.fields }
          { this.rackFields }
          { this.figures }
    
      </MyPinchZoomView>


      <Toolbar board={this} figures={this.figures}></Toolbar>
      <Text>{this.state.lastRefresh}</Text>
      <Moves game={this.props.game} lastRefresh={this.state.lastRefresh}/>
      <FlashMessage position="top" ref="errorMessage" />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass `scale` as a function param, i.e. `this.board(scale)`, or instead use the component as a child directly:

```
<Board
  scale={scale}
/>
```

Comment: When I am creating the board, I don't have a property scale, because the scale is a property of MyPinchZoomView. I cannot access scale from outside MyPinchZoomView, can I?

Answer (score 0):

Rather passing complete states (not recommended)

Pass values as props
such as

```
<ParentComponent>
      <ChildComponent dataOne={this.state.stateOfDataOne}/>
</ParentComponent>
```

then in your child component

```
<ChildComponent>
        <Text>{this.props.dataOne}</Text>
</ChildComponent>
```